# WordPress- How can I skip 3rd term from array for any specific post?

Tags: wordpress, post

Below is my code and I want to skip third term for the post.

```
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'boat-cat');
$cabins = array();

foreach ($terms as $term) {
$cabinsterm[]=$term->term_id;           
      $cabins[] = $term->name;
}

// print_r( $cabins);
```

Below is the code I tried

```
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'boat-cat');
$cabins = array();

$i=1;
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    
  $cabinsterm[]=$term->term_id; 
  if($i != 3){      
    $cabins[] = $term->name;
  }
  $i=$i+1;
  
}

// print_r( $cabins);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can continue when loop here 3

```
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'boat-cat');
$cabins = array();    
$i=1;
foreach ($terms as $term) {        
  $cabinsterm[]=$term->term_id; 
  if ($i == 3) {
   continue;
  }  
  $cabins[] = $term->name;      
  $i++;      
}
```